# cannot import name 'string_int_label_map_pb2'

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

My goal is to run tensorflow object detection API and followed the steps in the installation.

I install the tensorflow object detection API and protobuf.
I have also added the path to protobuf.
But the following error shoots up:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'string_int_label_map_pb2'
```

Installed protobuf :

```
%%bash
cd models/research
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

A block of code containing the error import statements:

```
from object_detection.utils import ops as utils_ops
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Install protoc-3.11.4 from
https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases

and run `protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.` as mentioned in the [installation instructions](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md). And  put [this](https://github.com/datitran/object_detector_app/blob/master/object_detection/protos/string_int_label_map_pb2.py) file in in object detection/protos

Comment: I run those cmds. But still the same error pop up and i use 3.6.1 version

Comment: @SaiKrishnadas if this is not working then put [this](https://github.com/datitran/object_detector_app/blob/master/object_detection/protos/string_int_label_map_pb2.py) file in  in object detection/protos

Comment: @SaiKrishnadas Replace and try

Comment: @SaiKrishnadas last thing I can advise is to follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md) and make sure protoc-3.11.4 is installed in your Coumputer

Comment: Warning: The second link you provide in your post is no longer available, you should update it.

Comment: @MohitChandel your solution for the file worked for me. Thank you so much...

Answer (score 3):

You can try this suggestion in the same order

see [models/issues/1962#](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1962#issuecomment-414203328)
Or

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
cd models/research

protoc -I=./ --python_out=./ ./object_detection/protos/*.proto
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim

import sys
sys.path.append('/content/models/research/object_detection') # ~/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection

#try import now..
from utils import label_map_util
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a simple path issue from this package so, we need to append the path of protos/string_int_label_map_pb2.py inside utils/label_map_util.py

instead of this
from objection_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2

it should be

import sys

sys.path.append("..")
from protos import string_int_label_map_pb2

Also, if you have done pip installation of object_detection then open these files from site-packages/objection_detection/utils.. else you can replace it in the git files under
model-master/research/objection_detection/utils.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that works for me is as follows:

If you are creating a **Virtual environment**:

Run the command after you create the environment to change the Google file `.protp` to `.py`:

`protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.`

However, if you are still facing an error, you can simply run the code on a google colab notebook:

**Protos Conversion to Python**

`%%cd /content/drive/MyDrive/TFOD1.x/models/research`

`!protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.`

get the file in protoc folder, then copy it into the >models>research>protoc
And (import step):
Copy the folder to your environment path:

For example:

C:\Users\x04xx18\Anaconda3\envs\tfod1.x\libs\protos

This should fix the error for you!